# i want to display only those images according to the category_id selected

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

i want to display only those images according to the category_id selected but iam not getting images here and and for all category_id the value showing is category_id=9

here is my controller

```
 public function men_clothing($p_id=null) 
{
    $data['active_mn']='men_clothing';

    $data['men']=$this->roxmodel->get_category_by_parent($p_id=8);
    $data['kids']=$this->roxmodel->get_category_by_parent($p_id=9);

    $config['base_url'] = base_url().'roxcontrol/men_clothing';
    $config['per_page'] = 9;
    $config['uri_segment'] = 3;
    $config['total_rows'] = $this->roxmodel->count_gallery();
    $data['galllery']=$this->roxmodel->get_gallery_men_images($p_id,$config['per_page'],$this->uri->segment(3));

    var_dump($data['galllery']);
    $this->load->library('pagination',$config);
    $data['page_links'] = $this->pagination->create_links();

    $this->load->view('men_clothing',$data);
}
```

here is my model

```
public function get_gallery_men_images($p_id=null)
  {
    $this->db->where('gallery.category_id',$p_id);
    $this->db->select('gallery.*,category.category_name');
    $this->db->join('category','category.id=gallery.category_id');
    return $this->db->get('gallery')->result();

  }
```

here is my view page

```
<ul class="sidebar-tags">
      <li><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>roxcontrol/men_clothing">View All  </a></li>
     <?php foreach($men as $row) {?>
      <li><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>roxcontrol/men_clothing/<?php echo $row->id; ?>"><?php echo $row->category_name; ?> <span> </span></a></li>
     <?php } ?>
</ul>



 <?php if( !empty($galllery) ) {
                                foreach($galllery as $row){?>

                                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                                        <div class="two-product">


                                            <!-- single-product start -->
                                            <div class="single-product">
                                            <!--    <span class="sale-text">Sale</span>-->
                                                <div class="product-img">
                                                    <a href="#">
                                                        <img class="primary-image" ima="<?php echo base_url();?>images/<?php echo $row->image;?>" src="<?php echo base_url();?>images/<?php echo $row->image;?>" alt="" />
                                                        <img class="secondary-image" ima="<?php echo base_url();?>images/<?php echo $row->image;?>" src="<?php echo base_url();?>images/<?php echo $row->image;?>" alt="" />

                                                    </a>
                                                    <div class="action-zoom">
                                                        <div class="add-to-cart">
                                                            <a href="<?php echo base_url()?>images/<?php echo $row->image ?>" data-toggle="modal-image"  title="Quick View"><i class="fa fa-search-plus"></i></a>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>

                                                <!--    <div class="price-box">
                                                        <span class="new-price">$110.00</span>
                                                    </div>-->
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="product-content">
                                                    <h2 class="product-name"><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>roxcontrol/product_details/<?php echo $row->id;?>/<?php echo $row->category_id;?>"><?php echo $row->title;?></a></h2>
                                                    <p><?php echo $row->description;?></p>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>

                                            <!-- single-product end -->
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <?php }}?>
```

here the image is not displaying and getting like this

```
SELECT `gallery`.*, `category`.`category_name` FROM `gallery` JOIN `category` ON `category`.`id`=`gallery`.`category_id` WHERE `gallery`.`category_id` = 9
```

my table(gallery) looks like this

```
id     image                category_id         
93   img1455604030.jpg       10              
94   img1455605183.jpg       11               
95   img1455616291.jpg       11                
96   img1455617201.jpg       10                
97   img1455617299.jpg       10                
98   img1455681918.jpg       13              
99   img1455681957.jpg       12
```

Comment: are you getting correct p_id there  in your model ??

Comment: var_dump($data['galllery']); what are you getting there

Comment: array (size=0)
  empty

Comment: do you have images there associate with these category id ??

Comment: yes..i will show my table now...

Comment: please show me your table structure

Comment: there is your problem in your join query missing from

Answer (score 0):

there is a problem in you **join** query

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('gallery');
$this->db->where('category.id',$p_id);
$this->db->join('category', 'category.id = gallery.category_id');


$query = $this->db->get()->result();
return $query;
```

Comment: now all images are displaying...while selecting category_id of different values

Comment: @MOHAMMED i have updated my answer please have a look

Comment: i got it..i had made some changes and find it out

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is to get or Filter result which has the same category_id: the query should be like this

```
public function get_gallery_men_images($p_id=null)
  {
    $img = $this->db->select('gallery.*')
         // why not add condition IF p_id = null
         // execute only if p_id not null otherwise it return error
         if($p_id != null):
         ->where('gallery.category_id',$p_id)
         endif;
          // we are using LEFT JOIN to fetch the category data's
         ->join('category','category.id=gallery.category_id', 'left')
         ->get('gallery');
    return $img->result();

  }
```